# Extract specific string from values in a column and excluding values that match specific string

Tags: python

I have a column with values like this

```
01_PLAGL1
02_PLAGL1
03_GRB10
04_GRB10
05_H19
06_H19
07_H19
control_11
control_12
# Actually it is longer that this but same pattern
```

And a need a list with this

```
PLAGL1, GRB10,H19
```

I don't need control

How can I do this?

Comment: Is the missing `L` in `02_PLAG1` a typo?

Comment: My bad! Sorry I will change this

Comment: thanks, so which output do you want? list/Series? duplicates/unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @Tim's answer, do you want something like?

```
out = (df
   .loc[~df['col'].str.startswith('control'), 'col']
   .str.extract(r'([^_]+)$', expand=False)
   .drop_duplicates().to_list()
)
```

output: `['PLAGL1', 'GRB10', 'H19']`

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.extract`:

```py
df["output"] = df["col"].str.extract(r'([^_]+)$')
```

Or maybe use `str.replace`:

```py
df["output"] = df["col"].str.replace(r'.*_', '')
```

Comment: Given the provided output, I think what OP might be looking for is more something like `df["col"].str.extract(r'([^_]+)$', expand=False).drop_duplicates().to_list()`

Comment: The `to_list()` option looks good, not sure about duplicates.

Comment: We'll see, I added another step as answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

This can remove all the rows with control in the dataframe.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df["Column"].str.split("_").tolist())
invalid_index = new_df[new_df[0] == "control"].index
df.drop(index = invalid_index, inplace = True)
```

|  | Column |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 01_PLAGL1 |
| 1 | 02_PLAG1 |
| 2 | 03_GRB10 |
| 3 | 04_GRB10 |
| 4 | 05_H19 |
| 5 | 06_H19 |
| 6 | 07_H19 |

Would appreciate some suggestions on improving this code!